# Create Dictionary from CSV file then connect to hostnames and run specific commands based on dictionary key

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, netmiko

I'm attempting to write a script that will connect to multiple devices that are pulled from a CSV file. I think based on my very limited python knowledge that creating a dictionary from a CSV file is the best way to do this.

The CSV File would have a header row with three headers, `hostname`, `device_platform`, & `device_role`. The device platform could be a few things like `cisco_ios`, & `broadcom_icos`.

So now I want to connect to each hostname using something like this:

```py
device_info = {
  'ip': hostname,
  'port': 22,
  'username': 'admin',
  'password': 'cisco123',
  'device_type': device_platform,
  'fast_cli': False
}
        
ssh_connection = ConnectHandler(**device_info)
```

Where for each hostname in the table it uses the `device_platform` for the device type.

Now to complicate things further, I want to run specific commands on each device based on it's device platform and device role.

So for example device roles commands would be something like this:

```py
VERIFCIATION_COMMANDS = {
  'cisco_ios':
    {
      'co-agg-r':
        [
          'term len 0', 'show processes cpu history', 'show processes cpu | i Core *', 'sh processes memory sorted',
          'sh process cpu sort 5sec | ex 0.00 +0.00 +0.00', 'show int | i line|packets/sec',
          'show int status | exclude disabled|notconnect', 'show etherchannel summary', 'show cdp neighbors',
          'show standby brief', 'show ip ospf neighbor', 'show ip bgp all summary', 'show int status | include err',
          'sh int desc | e admin down', 'sh int desc | i acc-sw', 'sh int desc | i dis-sw'
        ],
      'co-wlc':
        [
          'term len 0', 'show ap summary', 'show wlan summary', 'show wireless mobility sum',
          'show ip int bri | i Te|Gi', 'show cdp neighbors'
        ],
    },
  'cisco_asa':
    {
      'co-ics-fw':
        [
          'term pager 0', 'show failover state', 'show interface ip brief', 'show conn all', 'show arp'
        ]
    },
  'broadcom_icos':
    {
      'co-acc-rsw':
        [
          'terminal length 0', 'show port all', 'show ip interface brief', 'show ip ospf neighbor',
          'show lldp remote-device all', 'show isdp neighbors', 'show fiber-ports optical-transceiver all',
          'show udld all | include Enable'
        ]
    }
}
```

What would the best way be to accomplish this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is your code to actually accomplish this? Iterating through CSV data is not really an issue so please clarify this a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If the commands you need to run needs to be differentiated by name of the nodes, one option to ssh the each device's IP and get the name information.

If you have already the name and IP information in hand, you can create a dictionary as `{{'name': 'IP'}}` and use the name info to reach the IP you would like to connect.

For example: (A for loop will be needed to use.)

```
device_info= {
    'device_type': 'cisco',
    'ip': di['name'], # Which gives the IP information of the name. 
    'username': 'admin',
    'password': 'admin',
    'port': port
}
```